# Play video from list of video playlist, responsive video gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, jplayer

I have created a video playing content with jPlayer and additionally, I have added a video img thumbnail gallery to allow users to click and view additional video resources.

Furthermore, I have set the following features for the implementation of the video:

1.) The main video frame will automatically play the default video, this video will always be playing until a user chooses the next/new video

2.) User get to scroll through the scrollable video thumbnail gallery, each video Thumbnail will have a video title and brief description.

3.) When user selects any new video, the new video will replace the current playing video

4.) Users gets to exit the video at any point of the video and it will bring them back to the video page where they can select a new video.

Therefore, these are the following features that defines the behaviour of the video playing content.

***Issue:***

I have managed to set the video for the following features till feature3. Issue arises at feature 4, whereby when user selects the new video, the new video will be displayed, replacing the current video that is playing however, at this point, there is no way that the user can exit from the video.

I could only exit the video by either refreshing the page or clicking on the back button from the toolbar, this is a behaviour that I do not want. The user should be able to exit the video from the video that is playing.

Hence, how am I able to rectify the issue?? Thanks.

I have attached the code for perusal.

```js
$("#Reading_Video").jPlayer({

  ready: function() {},
  swfPath: "javascript",
  supplied: "webmv, ogv, m4v",
  loop: true,
  fullScreen: true,
  size: {
    width: 500,
    height: 500
  }
}).bind($.jPlayer.event.play, function() { // pause other instances of player when current one play
  $(this).jPlayer("pauseOthers");
}).bind($.jPlayer.event.click, function() {
  // allow for full screen
  console.log("fullscreen")
  var video_elem = document.getElementById("Reading_Video");
  if (video_elem.requestFullscreen) {
    video_elem.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (video_elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
    video_elem.msRequestFullscreen();
  } else if (video_elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    video_elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if (video_elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
    video_elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  }
});
$("#Reading_Video").jPlayer("setMedia", {
  //set m4v tag to array Footprints VideoList
  m4v: "lib/video/Video_1.mp4"
}).jPlayer("play");
$("#Reading_Video").show();
}

function loadVideo(event, videoID) {
  $("#EnjoyReading_Video").loadVideoByID(videoId);
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

```css
.playListContainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 180px;
  left: 1350px;
  height: 750px;
  width: 550px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.innerScroll {
  position: absolute;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.playListThumb {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  top: 25px;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.playListInfo {
  position: relative;
  right: 0px;
  left: 10px;
  top: 20px;
  float: right;
  width: 250px;
  height: 230px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.playListTitle {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #c66 !important;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.playListContent {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #000 !important;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<div id="ReadingPage" align="center" style="position:absolute; width:1920px; height:1080px; background-repeat: no-repeat; display: none; z-index=2; top:0px; left:1921px; ">

  <!--Video Div-->
  <div id="Reading_Video" style="position:absolute; left: 120px; top: 180px;"></div>

  <!--Video Thumbnail-->
  <div class="playListContainer">
    <div class="innerScroll">

      <div id="Thumbnail_1" style="position:relative; width:550px; height: 250px;" data-id="1" data-type="local">
        <a href="lib/video/ReadingVideo_1.mp4" onclick="loadVsideo(event, 1)">
          <div class="playListThumb">
            <img alt src="lib/img/Thumbnail_1.png" style="opacity:1;">
          </div>
          <div class="playListInfo" align="left">
            <p>
              <span class="playListTitle"><strong>Video Title</strong></span>
              <br>
              <span class="playListContent">Video Description</span>
            </p>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div id="Thumbnail_2" style="position:relative; width:550px; height: 250px" data-id="2" data-type="local">
        <a href="lib/video/ReadingVideo_2.mp4" onclick="loadVideo(event, 2)">
          <div class="playListThumb">
            <img alt src="lib/img/Thumbnail_2.png">
          </div>
          <div class="playListInfo" align="left">
            <p>
              <span class="playListTitle"><strong>Video Title</strong></span>
              <br>
              <span class="playListContent">Video Description</span>
            </p>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: _“the new video will be displayed in partial full screen”_ – what is “partial full screen”?

Comment: @CBroe have edited the sentence. Could you help?

Comment: If you want a custom close button in fullscreen – then put one into the element that you let display in fullscreen.

Comment: Basically, I do not want to have any controls, users to either click the screen to expand or restore screen

Comment: Well then what _do_ you want to happen? If you display anything in fullscreen, then the user has two options to get out of that again: Using what measure the browser UI provides for this task (usually it’s the `[esc]` key), or a custom control provided by the website, that makes it take the element out of fullscreen again when clicked.

Comment: @CBroe but the issue right now as stated is that I can escape from the full screen,meaning, I can t escape even when i press esc or by the click